# how to make list of promises without letting them invoked immediately

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to make `list of promises` .

and then with this code

```js
await Promis.all(List)
```

I can get all APi's together

the initial list is that

```js
const list = [
  {
    id: 1,
    action: async function () {
      console.log("1");
    },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    action: function () {
      console.log("2");
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    action: function () {
      console.log("3");
    },
  },
];
```

and I'm trying to make list of promise like that :

```js
list.forEach(item=>func_list.push(new Promise(item.func))) // problem is here
```

when I try to **push** `new Promise(item.func)`

every function **get called** and I don't want that .

I wanna to just make a list of promises .

How can I do that ?

Comment: When you make a new Promise and pass it a function, that function gets called. You cannot change that.

Comment: but it must be a way to

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: A promise is an object that produces a value at some point in the future. It isn’t something that can be called. You say that there *must* be a way, but the world isn’t obligated to change to work the way you think it does.

Comment: Or to put it slightly differently, maybe you want `() => new Promise` instead of just `new Promise`?

Comment: @JaredSmith — Promise.all expects an array of promises, not functions.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but you could trivially call `Promise.all(arrayOfFns.map(f => f()))` and it would delay the execution of the callback to the Promise constructor (as I'm sure you know)

Comment: I think you have a wrong idea of what a Promise is. You're basically asking "I want the confirmation and date of delivery but I don't want to make the purchase yet." Do you understand how there can not be a Promise without calling the function that starts the task that will eventually resolve the Promise. The same way that there can not be a delivery without purchase.

Comment: If you say "I promise this will return a value" but don't want to call it, then a promise is not what you really want to use here. Just save the raw functions and then call them later as you need them if this is what you want to do.